# Which values should be used for Mysql BOOL field: TRUE/FALSE or 1/0, why?

Tags: mysql, boolean

Will it make any difference to use FALSE/TRUE or 0/1 for BOOL/BOOLEAN field in mysql. Which one of them is better/safer to use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*The constants TRUE and FALSE evaluate to 1 and 0, respectively*; so there is no difference between using TRUE/FALSE or 1/0 .

Answer (score 5):

The BOOL and BOOLEAN field types are actually [synonyms for TINYINT(1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html#id889614), so int 0/1 makes most sense.